# converting german formatted CSV to xlsx in Power Automate

Tags: csv, xlsx, power-automate

What i found:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/convert-csv

The Problem in the example the character to seperate is "," -makes sense its called comma seperated..- however since I have to use German formatted csv i have to get along using ";" instead, heres an example:

```
Datum;Nummer;Zahl;KFZ;AB1;AB2;AB3;Name;Ort-1;Ortsteil;Straße + Hausnummer;Objekt;Ziel;Z-Ortsteil;Z-Straße + Hnr;Ziel Objekt;Ini;A 1;B 2;C 3;D 4;E 5;F 6;G 7 / H 8;SR A1;SR B2
08.07.2021;123456789;5;AB 12/34-56;123;123;;Mustermann, Muster;Musterstadt;Musterort;Musterstraße 2; ;Musterstadt;Musterstraße 1; Musterhaus Musterblick;01:02:03;02:03:04;03:04:05;04:05:06;05:06:07;07:08:09;;09:10:11;0;0;
```

It should look like this:
https://snipboard.io/FB8HXW.jpg

By now i tryed to edit the Code and i was thinking about replacing ";" with "","" but i didnt found a way to insert an " at the beginning of each line in Power-Automate.

Sadly i wasnt able to get it work by now, maybe someone here can help me out.

Comment: If you want to change the separator and datetime or decimal formats, you could try the CSV Lint plugin for Notepad++ https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ it has a "Reformat" option

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might want to use the -delimiter feature in Import-csv.
[See online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.1)

Example 2 shows creating a csv file using semicolon as the separator,  and then importing it.

Sadly, the same feature won't convert numbers from German format to English format.  This has to do with whether decimal fractions are introduced by a comma or a period.